# PHP signup form with mysqli does not register new user

Tags: php, html, mysql, passwords

I have a PHP file that worked before but since i added a few rows to my database it wont store the new variables in the database. After I fill in the form and submit it I do get a: 'signup=success' message.

Connection to database is working, all the names that need to match between Database, PHP file and HTML file are matching.

```
else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, gender, birthdate, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssisis", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $phonenumber, $gender, $birthdate, $hashedPwd);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
                exit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` and `mysqli_stmt_execute()` return? What about `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)`?

Comment: As an aside, phone numbers aren't integers (you lose leading zeros).

Comment: @LegendofPedro i'm sorry new to php how do i check what they return? and good point changed it. i personally have a feeling the problem is something to do with 'gender' being a radio button in the html file? could this be?

Comment: Check the error: `if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {  echo mysqli_error($conn); }` As you have it, you immediately redirect away, but mysqli will error silently and requires a check.

Comment: And birthdate is being passed in as an integer value - what is the column type?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski int, that is the best type to give a birthdate right?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i get this returned: Incorrect date value: '2006' for column `userssosch`.`users`.`birthdate` at row 1

Comment: @BertVanHecke MySQL's date type is often a better choice than an int because it allows you to work directly with all MySQL's date handling functions. If you are passing in and storing an int though, you may need to do some modifications of the date value received from the html form before storing it.

Comment: Oh, that suggests that your birthdate _is_ a MySQL DATE column already, and is not an int. What was the exact original value submitted by the form that resulted in `2006` being passed to mysql? You may need to edit above to add a snip of your form.

Comment: MySQL would expect you to pass it a string value in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` for a date column.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes indeed, it works now thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the date being stored in as an int while in the database it had a column type of date and this stores a string and not an int.

Thanks for the useful answers!

Answer (score -1):

Try showing intermediate values to debug the issue

```php
$hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssisis", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $phonenumber, $gender, $birthdate, $hashedPwd);
echo "<br>\n";
$r = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
echo $r;
echo "<br>\n";
if (!r) { echo mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>\n"; }
echo mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) == 1) {
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    //header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
    exit();
}
```

`echo`, `print_r` and `fprintf` are used to print values.